# How to solve $a \cos \alpha + b \sin \alpha = c$ for $\alpha$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, physics

I'm solving a physics problem and I came down to solving an equation of the form
 $$a \cos \alpha + b \sin \alpha = c$$

Can someone help me to solve this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Comment: Or set $a=r\cos A,b=r\sin A$

Comment: @Edward While the responses are right, next time show us a particular example. We can help you through step by step if needed. Things may become much clearer I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, then there is an angle $\theta$ with $a=r\cos\theta, b=r\sin\theta$.  Now the equation becomes $$r\cos\theta\cos\alpha+r\sin\theta\sin\alpha=c\\ \cos(\alpha-\theta)=c/r$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ And then use sine formula for $\sin(a+b)$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos\alpha+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin\alpha=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
Now there's $\beta$, such that : 
$$\cos\beta\cos\alpha+\sin\beta\sin\alpha=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
or
$$\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Comment: There should be a square root in the denominator on RHS.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Express $$\sin\alpha=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},\cos\alpha=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
$$t=\tan(\alpha/2)$$